# Referral sessions between subdomains tracked with different views in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

One of the Google Analytics properties I manage tracks multiple subdomains.

Subdomains are tracked through views created in this property using filters to include only traffic for the subdomain.

I've noticed that these subdomain views do not include data on source/medium coming through other subdomains on the same property.

Can views under the same property track source/medium session coming in from views under same property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a.example.com and b.example.com in the Referral Exclusion List at the property level, so those referrals will be swapped to Direct.
This is normal behavior to avoid interrupting sessions on the same domain.

You can get more information here:
https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/08/11/subdomain-tracking-google-analytics/

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thank you!